# Event error: Windows cannot query DllName registry entry for {...}

Tags: windows, windows-registry, dll

My Windows event log is full of Application Errors like:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Userenv
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1041
Date:       2016-03-07
Time:       11:19:36 AM
User:       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Computer:   SERVER99
Description:
Windows cannot query DllName registry entry for {CF7639F3-ABA2-41DB-97F2-81E2C5DBFC5D} 
and it will not be loaded. This is most likely caused by a faulty registration.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

I've not searched exhaustively but it appears the addresses are only `{CF7639F3-ABA2-41DB-97F2-81E2C5DBFC5D}` and `{7B849a69-220F-451E-B3FE-2CB811AF94AE}`. Microsoft's site is [singularly unhelpful](https://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2.3790.5491&EvtID=1041&EvtSrc=Userenv&FileVer=5.2.3790.5491&FileName=userenv.dll&EvtType=Error&LCID=):

> "There is no additional information about this issue in the Error and Event Log Messages or Knowledge Base databases at this time. You can use the links in the Support area to determine whether any additional information might be available elsewhere."

I found a few threads that indicating (in|unin)stalling [IE8 is at fault](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/error-mess-n-event-log/77ac2120-7867-43df-a8dd-51250eb511e0?auth=1) and searching for and [deleting the key](https://community.spiceworks.com/windows_event/show/145-userenv-1041) within `{}` braces is a cure. Having once too often been victim of self-inflicted [cargo-cult](https://lonesysadmin.net/2011/10/19/cargo-cult-system-administration/) [sys-admin](http://blog.lastinfirstout.net/2009/11/cargo-cult-system-administration.html) I prefer to not go blindly removing registry entries. Before I do that is there anyone here have better advice or insight as to the real cause?

If OS version is relevant, the computer is Windows Server 2003 R2 x64, updates relatively current (about 1 month behind).

Comment: It's a registry error. Please follow the tip gave there: http://serverfault.com/questions/576831/how-do-i-know-if-a-dll-is-registered and find for what DLL it's. After run regsvr32 -u <filename>.dll

Comment: @yagmoth555 thanks! I tried it but doesn't seem to work here. Only 2 keys exist for each of the {...}, they're not under HKCR\CSID\*, and none of them contain any values (they're blank), so we still don't know what the file name is -- and perhaps this is exactly what the event log is complaining about. (\* "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GPExtensions" and Wow6432Node of same)

Comment: If the regsvr32 registry is corrupt, backup the registry, but remove those keys then.